# Convergence of integral using Taylor's polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, integration, taylor-expansion, improper-integrals

I stumbled accross this question and would like to know if my approach makes sense, and if there is a better one:

For which values of $t$ does the following integral converge?

$$\int_1^\infty e^{1/x}-t(\sin(\frac1x)+\cos(\frac1x)) dx$$

I thought of using Taylor's polynomial to the 2nd degree, and using Lagrange's form of the remainder block the integral between two easier integrals, then showing it converges iff $t=1$. Is there a better approach?

Comment: At infinity, the integrand goes to $1-t$, so if $t\ne 1$, the integral diverges.

Comment: You can also make the substitution $ t=1/x$ and then use MVT.